# Sunburst Chart with percentage

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I would like to create a chart similar to this:

https://www.typologycentral.com/wiki/images/2/27/Personality_Graph.png

I'm able to create a sunburst chart using Highcharts (any library would be fine) but can't find a way to add in percentages.

I'm trying to show the percentage completed for each section of the chart e.g.

Ring / Layer 1: each course would take up a quarter of the first ring

- HTML Course       Value: 25      Completed 25 // section would be fully shaded
- PHP Course        Value: 25      Completed 0  // section would be unshaded
- JavaScript Course Value: 25      Completed 12.5 // section would be half shaded
- CSS Course        Value: 25      Completed 0  // section would be unshaded

Thank you

Comment: Could you reproduce your current attempt on some online editor with the sample data?

Comment: This is the basic setup that I am hoping to use:  
https://jsfiddle.net/3bkjL8sm/  

I'm looking to ideally do something like this:  
  
    id: '1.1',  
     parent: '0.0',  
     name: 'Africa',  
     max value: 25,  // the maximum value for that segment  
     actual value: 10 // the current value to shade in  
  
Thank you

Comment: I am afraid that Highcharts doesn't support this type of data structure in the sunburst series. All you can do (without customization) is add a dummy series and calculate data for each of it, take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ya19cdgx/ You can also report idea about implementing this feature on the highcharts user voice channel: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

Comment: Thank you @SebastianWędzel - this will definitely do the job I need it to for the time being. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can also consider to use solidgauge series - https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity